# How downgrade version of subdependency in gradle

Tags: java, gradle, dependencies

I have a config in build.gradle:

```
implementation('org.springframework.boot:3.0.0')
implementation('org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui') //depends on org.springframework.boot:2.7.5
```

Is there any way to use spring-boot 3.0.0 dependency in my project but spring-boot 2.7.5 as a dependency for springdoc-openapi-ui?

I feel that project Jigsaw could help me to separate scopes of such dependencies, but would be grateful for more specific lead.

Comment: How would you expect that to work? You can only have one version of Spring Boot on your classpath (or at least, if there are multiple, the classloader will load referenced classes from the first version it finds). Given the big changes in Spring Boot 3.0, a dependency for Spring Boot 2.7 will likely not just work. Jigsaw wouldn't help either, because that springdoc-openapi-ui would still need to interact with the Spring Boot 3.0 runtime, which wouldn't work if you could isolate the dependency with Jigsaw, because then they would be two distinct sets of classes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to mention the version of springdoc-openapi-ui that you want to use.

You can check the versions from [MvnRepository link](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springdoc/springdoc-openapi-ui) and how to add them via gradle.